# gas vs gasLimit in web3.js

Tags: web3js, gas, gas-price, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I've seen a bunch of stackoverflow posts on this and want to make sure I've got it right. I'm running into an issue where on test networks I can do this:

```js
  contract.methods.mint(1).send({
      from: account,
      value: String(38100000000000000),
    })
```

and it works absolutely fine. However, on the mainnet, for some reason this gives me the warning "transaction likely to fail". I dug into this and it seems like this is because I'm not specifying the gas (again, I don't know why this only happens on mainnet). So I ended up doing this:

```js
let gasEstimate = await contract.methods.mint(1).estimateGas({gas: 5000000, value: String(38100000000000000), from: account});

contract.methods.mint(1).send({
      from: account,
      value: String(38100000000000000),
      gas: gasEstimate,
      gasLimit: gasEstimate * 2
   })
```

Does this make sense? Or will this cause metamask to automatically show the 'gasLimit' to users instead of the suggested "gas" parameter. Still not 100% certain what the difference between 'gas' and 'gasLimit' is.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. There's no `gasLimit` property in send, see the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send), there is `gasPrice` and `gas`.

Comment: okay got it thanks, I removed the 'gas' parameter.